# Question re Shipping

Tags: cartthrob

Quick question re setting up shipping prices. I'm setting up a store selling books and need to calculate shipping on the basis of book size, essentially: light, normal and heavy. This is/can be set in the channel entry.

What I need then is to set prices for the US, UK, Europe and Asia taking into account these variables of light, normal and heavy. I.e. there would be these three shipping rates for each location but calculated at checkout (or before).

Is there a plugin needed for this? Or what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

CartThrob gives you a built-in shipping option "By location - weight".

The CT documentation is pretty poor in general and very limited on this topic, but such information as there is can be found [here](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/shipping/index.html#by-location-weight-threshold).

Simply put if you choose this option in CT shipping options, you are given a table into which you can put country codes and threshold weights.  What you would need to do is assign either the actual weight of each book (if your shipping options are based on this) or assign each book a dummy weight to put it into the appropriate shipping option.

As far as I can tell, the table works similarly to other shipping systems in CT, simply by scanning down the table of coutnries / weight thresholds until it finds a combination that matches the item being considered, and then associates the shipping charge of that row of the table to the item.  So setting up the table will require you to enter 9 rows (three for each country) with the rows in ascending weight order.

HTH

PS - you usually get better replies to questions if you note the version of EE and (in this case) CT in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the docs are not all they could be - seems confusing and badly laid out sometimes.